# Programmatically ignore children with nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I'm just trying to get my head around nHibernate and have a query. When setting up the mappings file (with Fluent or regular .hbm.xml files) you specify relationships (bags; one-to-many, etc) and sub-types - the idea being (I believe) is that when you fetch an object it also fetches and matching data. My question is can I programmatically tell my query to ignore that relationship?

So, below, there is a Foo class with a list of Bar objects. Within the mappings file this would be a one-to-many relationship and sometimes I want to retrieve a Foo with all Bars BUT sometimes I want to just retrieve the Foo object without the Bar, for performance reasons. How can I do this?

```
public class Foo { public int Id { get; set; } public List<Bar> { get; set; } }
public class Bar { public int Id { get; set; }
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The relationship shouldn't be loaded automatically unless you turn off Lazy Loading or specify it to be eager loaded in the query.

**Edit:**

To answer your questions in the comment below.

1) It's done as part of the query. An basic example using QueryOver in NHibernate 3.0 would look something like:

```
var result = Session.QueryOver()
                    .Fetch(x => x.Category).Eager
                    .Where(x => x.Price > 10)
                    .List();
```

I think with ICriteria it's "SetFetchMode("Category", FetchMode.Eager)"

2) If you turn off lazy-loading on the mapping for an object, it will effectively always be eager loaded. Tho I suggest you eager load on a query-by-query basis to avoid the possibility of having a massive chain of data loaded, or loading data you don't actually need.

Comment: Alright cheers, things springs off two questions: 1) Specifying eager loading in the query is via the NHibernateUtils.Initilize method? 2) Can I specify the eager loading per object or once specified is it specified for the entire object? Ideally it'd be a situation where I choose which items I want eager loaded

Comment: how should this be solved in a silverlight application (without ria, just wcf) where lazyloading is not an option?

Comment: @randoms - You eagerly fetch the data, like mentioned in the answer, then map the object to a DTO and pass the DTO back to the client. Don't pass the NH Poco back.