# ignore HasMany relationship programmatically?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I got a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505826/programmatically-ignore-children-with-nhibernate) question.

I use Silverlight and WCF, where lazyloading isn't an option. How can i ignore a HasMany relation programmatically in some cases improve performance? (I just want the Foo's without the related Bars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you're trying to do is not possible, be it NHibernate or Fluent. You can't have mapping saying *"sometimes load, sometimes not"*. Setting `Not.LazyLoad()` is pretty much **show stopper** - NHibernate **will load collection always, entirely**.

Those kind of optimization (*sometimes load, sometimes not*) are better suited to be handled at [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) part of your model. For example, you could have your `FooDao` class looking like this:

```
public class FooDao
{
    public IList<Foo> GetFoosEagerly()
    {
        // load all Foos first; then all Bars for every Foos
        var foos = session.QueryOver<Foo>().List();
        foreach (var foo in foos)
        {
            NHibernateUtil.Initialize(foo.Bars);
        }

        return foos;
    }

    public IList<Foo> GetFooPerformanceCritical()
    {
        return session.QueryOver<Foo>().List();
    }
}
```

With standard mapping (as in, **not** using `Not.LazyLoad()`), first method will still return Foos with Bars collection fully set (we just need to tell NHibernate to load them now, before we return). However, second one tho will return `Foo` objects **only**. No single `Bar` will be loaded. Instead, NHibernate will generate proxy object in place of Bars collection for every `Foo`.

Your WCF service can use such DAO object internally. Naturally, you can have similar methods to load single Foo.

Conclusion is simple; mappings alone won't help you with your problem. You need to do some extra coding work, but it definitely is possible.

Comment: I did not quite get that. When i Request Foo's, i automatically get all the related Foo.Bars, since i have a mapping HasMany(x => x.Bars).Not.LazyLoad(); in my Foo mapping file. And yes, as i wrote, i use WCF services.

Comment: @randoms: I see what you mean. Long story short; it's not possible. See my edit to give you some ideas how to overcome this problem.